# Detecting hardware breakpoints in Linux

Tags: c, debugging, reverse-engineering

I am trying to implement some minimal anti-reversing protection for a commercial Linux software. Calculating the checksum of the executable seems to protect against software breakpoints. Is there a way to detect hardware breakpoints in Linux?

Comment: What if I [run you program under a VM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702358/debugging-userland-program-full-of-anti-debug-through-vmware?rq=1)?

Comment: Hardware breakpoint means hardware support right? Thus depending on your architecture you could find which registers are set when an hardware breakpoint is active, and try to read them (if they can be read...). See for instance [ARM Debug registers](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0432c/BABJHEIG.html)

Comment: Linux runs on a lot of architectures, and there is no portable way to do this. You also didn't say which architecture you want to detect this.

Answer (score 1):

Seems not, as it is the processor that does the break when conditions in its debug registers are met, i.e. the program code doesn't change.

And you can't protect [easily] against software breakpoints either when the program is taken into a debugger when/while running: the debugger will replace an instruction with an instruction that causes and exception, catches the exception, halts the program, shows the registers and when you want it to continue, restores the instruction, etc.

Though many years ago I tried to crack DBASE and found a very clever trick: the program checked at some point if the next instruction was an `INT 3` instruction (software breakpoint), and if so, jumped into nothingness. Took me days to find that trick...